# TypeError: 'RegexValidator' object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-validation

I was building integer array field for **color**.

I tried to use CommaSeparatedIntegerField but it was depreated

```
CommaSeparatedIntegerField has been deprecated. 
Support for it (except in historical migrations) will be removed in Django 2.0.
    HINT: Use CharField(validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list]) instead
```

So I used set the color field as `CharField` instead of `CommaSeparatedIntegerField`as recommended

```
from django.core.validators import validate_comma_separated_integer_list

class Cloth(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(validators=validate_comma_separated_integer_list)
```

But I'm getting this error when I makemigrations

```
TypeError: 'RegexValidator' object is not iterable
```

Why am I getting this error? I followed the exact guideline :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

first of all `CharField` requires a `max_length` field and `validators` need to be in a `list` `[]`

so,

```
class Cloth(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list],max_length=100)
```

Comment: Cool thanks. it works. Could I ask one more thing? What default value should be the for this field?

Comment: I'm not sure because it's array integer field and at the same time it's char field. Does `default='[]'` work?

Comment: if you need to keep a blank thing, make blank=True and null=True, if you are planning not to keep data for each row in the color field

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884850/how-to-paginate-queryset-for-serializer